# I'm following a coding tutorial on making an AI assistant (Mikael codes), but it gives me the errors, even if the code is the same as in the example

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, text-to-speech, voice, python-3.11

I copied the text letter by letter in the initialization chapter of the video, and I ran it when he did. I installed `pocketsphynx`, `datetime`, `speech_recognition`, `pyttsx3`, `webbrowser`, `wikipedia` and `wolfaramalpha` (and `loggin.config`). However, after looking in the comments, I did not find any answers. I ran it when he did (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqFI_g8vAoc) the first time, and no matter what, it gives me the same errors.

I tried asking chatgpt, but that did not help, I tried to look on the comments section of the video, and I tried self diagnosing the problem.

My code was:

```
from datetime import datetime
from logging.config import listen
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3 
import webbrowser
import wikipedia
import wolframalpha
 
# Speech engine initialisation
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id) # 0 = male, 1 = female
activationWord = 'computer' # Single word
 
def speak(text, rate = 120):
    engine.setProperty('rate', rate)
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()
 
def parseCommand():
    listener = sr.Recognizer()
    print('Listening for a command')
 
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        listener.pause_threshold = 2
        input_speech = listener.listen(source)
 
    try: 
        print('Recognizing speech...')
        query = listener.recognize_google(input_speech, language='en_gb')
        print(f'The input speech was: {query}')
    except Exception as exception:
        print('I did not quite catch that')
        speak('I did not quite catch that')
        print(exception)
        return 'None'
 
    return query
 
 
 
# Main loop
if __name__ == '__main__':
    speak('All systems nominal.')
 
    while True:
        # Parse as a list
        query = parseCommand().lower().split()
 
        if query[0] == activationWord:
            query.pop(0)
 
            # List commands
            if query[0] == 'say':
                if 'hello' in query:
                    speak('Greetings, all.')
                else: 
                    query.pop(0) # Remove say
                    speech = ' '.join(query)
                    speak(speech)
```

And the errors that it gave me were:

```txt
Listening for a command
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\_____\.vscode\Python\AI voice\main.py", line 26, in parseCommand
    input_speech = listener.listen(source)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\_______\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 651, in listen
    assert source.stream is not None, "Audio source must be entered before listening, see documentation for ``AudioSource``; are you using ``source`` outside of a ``with`` statement?"
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AssertionError: Audio source must be entered before listening, see documentation for ``AudioSource``; are you using ``source`` outside of a ``with`` statement?

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\______\.vscode\Python\AI voice\main.py", line 48, in <module>
    query = parseCommand().lower().split()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\_____\.vscode\Python\AI voice\main.py", line 24, in parseCommand
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "C:\Users\_______\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 201, in __exit__        
    self.stream.close()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Comment: The value of `source` is `None`. I haven't used the `speech_recognition` library, but my guess is that it's something either with your microphone (or OS permissions) or a missing driver or something. Make sure you've installed the necessary requirements (for example: https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/#pyaudio-for-microphone-users)

Comment: It appears that your sound/microphone are not the same as the tutorial.

Comment: This code works for me on Windows with my usb logitec headset.